# How can I close the last column of this document?

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
 LocationProvider & Description & blalala \\
 \hline
 network & Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
 location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS
 Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
 location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
 location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
 location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS. \\
\hline
gps & Use the GPS receiver in the Android device to determine the best
location via satellites. Usually better precision than network. \\
\hline
passive & Allows to participate in location of updates of other components
to save energy \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have declared three columns, so you have to use all of them to have the rules. That is, you need exactly two (number of columns minus one) `&` in each line of the table

Comment: How can I add something like this above of the table?                                                                                           1) Name three points that most caught your attention in the video.

Comment: Probably yes, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Where do you do want to add that?

Comment: On the top of the table.

Comment: You mean like a caption?  You can write `\caption{Name ... video}` before the `\begin{tabularx}`.  Otherwise just typing the text there should do...

Comment: @AnaPauladosAnjosVitorasse.-- please have a look at the answer below -- the captions can be added in two ways -- enclosing in a `table` environment and using the syntax `\caption...` or -- without the `table` environ simply add one row at the top of the table with centered text as the caption -- your choice -- I have also added an option to remove verticals and free the content from a `jailed` impact

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? If yes, then accept it. If not, then please leave a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
        \hline
        LocationProvider & Description & blalala \\
        \hline
        network 
            & Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS
        Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS.
                & \\
        \hline
        gps 
            & Use the GPS receiver in the Android device to determine the best
        location via satellites. Usually better precision than network. 
                &\\
        \hline
        passive 
            & Allows to participate in location of updates of other components
        to save energy 
                &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**for the caption**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
                \caption{Something to describe the table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X  X  X }
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{1.  Something to describe the table}\\
        \toprule
        LocationProvider & Description & blalala \\
        \midrule
        network 
            & Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS
        Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS.
                & \\
        \midrule
        gps 
            & Use the GPS receiver in the Android device to determine the best
        location via satellites. Usually better precision than network. 
                &\\
        \midrule
        passive 
            & Allows to participate in location of updates of other components
        to save energy 
                &\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**since the center column is too long**

using `p` type column with fixed width

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell}
 \renewcommand\theadfont{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{3cm}  X  p{1.5cm} }
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{1.  Something to describe the table}\\
        \toprule
        \thead{LocationProvider} & \thead{Description} & \thead{blalala} \\
        \midrule
        network 
            & Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS
        Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPSUses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS.
                & \\
        \midrule
        gps 
            & Use the GPS receiver in the Android device to determine the best
        location via satellites. Usually better precision than network. 
                &\\
        \midrule
        passive 
            & Allows to participate in location of updates of other components
        to save energy 
                &\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear. You should provide more information as are:

- Used document class.
- Page layout (one or two column document, size of `\textwidth`, ...)
- More realistic mimic of real table (size of cells contents in the third column is unknown)
- what you mean with title of question: "How to close the last column of this document?" I don't see any problem with the last column.

In lack of the above information, we can only guessing, what is your the real problem, so probably all our suggestion is off-topic. In suggested solution below is assumed, that table is in an article with default settings, where
is used packages.

- `booktabs` for horizontal rules in table
- `makecell` for writing column headers
- `microtype` for better spacing text in cells
- `ragged2e` for "smart" hyphenation of text in cells.

Proposed solution is based on my taste how I would design such a table (meaning very opinion based):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
 \renewcommand\theadgape{}
 \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
 \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table caption}
\label{tab:...}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L{1.5}  L{0.5} @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Location\\Provider} & \thead{Description} & \thead{blalala} \\
    \midrule
network & Uses the mobile network or W-Fi to determine the best
        location.Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS
        Uses the mobile network or Wi-Fi to determine the best location. Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS Uses the mobile network or Wi-Fi to determine the best. Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS Uses the mobile network or WI-Fi to determine the best location. Might have a higher precision in closed rooms than GPS.
                &   Unknown size and type of the content \dots\\
    \addlinespace
GPS     & Use the GPS receiver in the Android device to determine the best
        location via satellites. Usually better precision than network.
                &   \\
    \addlinespace
passive & Allows to participate in location of updates of other components
        to save energy
                &   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]